# Git subproject: how to get original files

Tags: git, github, push

I'm new to git and have to use it for working on school projects. I have a git repo locally that is linked to the remote repo already. I just created a new branch using git branch and pushed my updated code to the new branch. When I check the remote repo, this [image: this] is in my src directory instead of the directory that contains my java files. How do I get git to push the actual java files instead of that?

Comment: i think you could have mad some mistakes pls ensure you followed these steps. $ : git add <filename> $ : git commit -m "Commit message" $ :git push. before you do git add do  $: git status this shows you what all files have been changed in your local and the do git add those files.

Comment: A *submodule* (which GitHub represents with that arrow thing) means that the files are in *a different Git repository*. The "superproject" that uses the "subproject" or submodule does not contain the submodule's source, it just says "go over there `--> bfeee...` to get the files". (There are two parts to the "over there", one is the *repository* and the other is the `bfeee...` commit-ID.)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps you need:

1. First find out the commit ID for your changes using `git log --author="your_username"`
2. Now shift to the main remote branch(suppose its master) `git checkout master`
3. Now pick that commit id using `git cherry-pick YOUR_COMMIT_ID`
4. Now give `git push origin master`
5. In remote give `git pull origin master` (If applicable)